# Calculating probability with Gaussian variable

Tags: probability

Let $X$ be a Gaussian variable, with $E(x) = m$ and variance $VAR(x) = σ^2$.
How can I calculate $P(X>m)$ and $P(|X-m| > kσ)$?
About the first, I read a paragraph that was explaining similar so I started doing something like this: 
$$P(x<m) = (x-m<0) = P(\frac{x-m}{σ}) = P(Z<0) = (???)$$

Any hints?

Comment: $P(Z<0)$, $P(Z>0)$ and $P(Z=0)$ should be easy for a standard normal distribution, and so $P(X>m)$.

Comment: @Henry Right, now I see...